# Restrict a filter to a custom post type. Am I doing this right?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

So I had this little bit of code to short a music charts custom post type that all starts with  numbers (the trick was to make the 10th position appear last in the list, not between 1 and 2):

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'orderby_post_title_int', 10, 2 );
function orderby_post_title_int( $orderby ) { return '(wp_posts.post_title+0) ASC'; }
```

This was working well until I discovered that is was also changing every other posts ;-)

So I tried wrapping the filter around a conditionnal statement:

```
if ($post_type == 'chart') { 
    add_filter('posts_orderby', 'orderby_post_title_int', 10, 2 );
}
```

Didn't work. Then I decided to go within the function like this :

```
function orderby_post_title_int( $orderby, $query ) {
    if ($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'chart') {
       return '(wp_posts.post_title+0) ASC';
    }
    return $orderby;  
}
```

And still nothing. At this point, it doesn't change the regular post, but won't change the chart post type either.

So I guess my question is: am I in the right direction here? Is it possible to restrict a filter to a specific custom post type? If so, what should I explore as a way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Your last attempt is what I would have tried. If `get_post_type()` doesn't work, I would dump $query to see what you have. `error_log( print_r($query, true) );` It's there somewhere.

Comment: Your last block of code should work, and when I test it it does. You say: "So I had this little bit of code to short a music charts custom post type that all **starts with numbers**..." which implies that there are characters besides numbers, yet you "caste" to a number with `+0`. Are you sure that isn't skewing the results?

Comment: @s_ha_dum true, I'll have to consider this. The titles are indeed written like "Number from 1 to 10. Title of album". Although I'm fairly sure this should be sorted all right, to be frank, I'm just not seeing how else I should do it.

Comment: @clifgriffin will be dumping that soon to see what lies in it!

Comment: "9 Title of Album" will just be "9" if you try to caste it with "+0". I very much doubt that will sort correctly.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Hum, I should indeed try to concatenate rather than add to the title, that's for sure. Will be trying that later on today. Although, in the very first case, it did the job very well doing the +0 trick. It's just that it changed every post type, not only the one I needed...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the "conditional" [get_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Post_Type).

In your case it would be:

```
function orderby_post_title_int( $orderby, $query ) {
    if ( 'chart' == get_post_type() ) {
       return '(wp_posts.post_title+0) ASC';
    }
    return $orderby;  
}
```

Or you could insert the conditional in your original function, which you know was working?

(Note if this is a custom post type archive, you'd use the [is_post_type_archive()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) conditional instead.)

Comment: Just tried and sadly, it changes nothing :(